# Extract the "mid/center-point" of the touching borders/lines of adjacent polygons

Tags: qgis, vertices, extract, adjacency

I have a layer with several polygons and want to extract the "mid/center-point" of the touching borders/lines of adjacent polygons. Despite trying several methods, I do not know how to achieve what I had wanted.

What I tried recently:

1. I used **Polygons to lines** to convert the polygons to lines
2. I then used **Explode lines** to split the lines at vertices

But Explode lines just splits at all of its vertices. I am thinking that the steps might be to:

1. Convert the polygons to lines
2. Split the lines at vertices only if there is one or more line touching the vertex (like splitting the lines only where the black dots are as shown in the screenshot below):

[image: Split at vertices]

3. Find the mid-point (point coordinates) of each of the resulting split lines (which would be the red dots below):

[image: Mid-points of split lines]

What are the steps and algorithms needed to achieve this (extract/get the red dots as shown in the image)?

**Update**: I tried QChainage plugin but not all common vertices were extracted (like these green circles):

[image: QChainage test]

Comment: There's a "split lines" algorithm, have you tried that?

Comment: In ArcGis there is a dissolve lines, no multiparts option. Most likely similar thing exists in qgis. No need to split at vertices after step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download the [QChainage](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qchainage/) From the plugin repository
2. Open the plugin under **Vector > QChainage**
3. Select the layer under the "Basic" tab
4. Under the "Advanced" tab, put "2" into "Divide Features into _ Parts" and execute
5. Start an edit session on the resultant layer
6. Use **Vector > Research Tools > Select by location** to select the points in the resultant layer which intersect the start and endpoints of the original lines
7. Delete these features
8. Save edits

**EDIT:**

It seems that your lines are not topologically correct, in that some of your lines are touching other lines' endpoints without being split into a new line. To fix this, use **Processing Toolbox > GRASS GIS > [v.clean](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.clean.html)** and select the "break" option for the "tool" parameter. That should break all of your lines into individual segments.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the steps but not all common vertices in the original line layer were extracted. Please see new screenshot above.

Comment: @JAT86 I updated by answer with a tool you can use to break the lines at intersections.

Comment: QChainage though does not preserve the feature attributes. Is there an alternative way/method to also include the attributes for the created midpoints?

Comment: I would suggest doing a spatial join of the source line features to the points.

Comment: I do not know if it is my source file that is the problem, but even though I used GRASS v.clean (break) on the original line layer, several midpoints resulting from QChainage do not get the attributes from the lines after doing a "Join attributes by location". (By the way, the line layer itself was converted from a multipolygon layer using the MMQGIS plugin's "Convert" function. I am just not sure if the conversion had an effect on the topology of the original borders..)

Comment: I cannot speak much to the effects of your transformation process from multipolygon to polyline but it may be work checking to see if the line features have been duplicated somehow, or otherwise mangled. If you are having trouble getting the attributes of the lines into the point features, try performing a very short buffer on either the lines or the points, and using it in the spatial join operation.